# Help in measuring the current through the collector and base in order to find beta for a transistor

Tags: transistors, current

I've set up the following circuit in order to measure beta for a BC547B transistor.

The readings I get are by 2 different methods:

- Method 1 by measuring the current through the collector and the base directly by breaking the circuit between the resistors and the relevant legs of the transistor.
- Method 2 by measuring the voltage across R1 and R2 and dividing by each resistance.

Both methods give results that are comparable: Ic = 3.0mA and Ib = 2.3mA, which give beta = 1.3. From the datasheet, beta should be at least 200. What is going wrong?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSp9S5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: In the saturated case (your case) you have:
$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{C}} &= \frac{R_2\cdot\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)+R_3\cdot\left(V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)}{R_3\cdot R_1+R_3\cdot R_2+R_1\cdot R_2}
\\\\
I_{_\text{B}} &= \frac{R_1\cdot\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{BE}}\right)-R_3\cdot\left(V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_\text{CE}}\right)}{R_3\cdot R_1+R_3\cdot R_2+R_1\cdot R_2}
\end{align*}$$
Assuming \$V_{_\text{BE}}=700\:\text{mV}\$ and \$V_{_\text{CEsat}}=200\:\text{mV}\$ then that works out to \$I_{_\text{C}}=3.1\:\text{mA}\$ and \$I_{_\text{B}}=2.6\:\text{mA}\$.

Comment: @periblepsis I'm glad that your calculations roughly agree with my experimental results but please could you explain where these formulae come from. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, you're saturating the transistor. In saturation, the collector current is controlled by its load, while you are delivering a huge base current.

A quick way to measure beta ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fySPyF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Given the range of beta, and its variability, this will be quite accurate enough for most purposes.

Calculate the base current from R1. VBE will be about 0.6 V, measure the battery voltage, deduct 0.6, and divide by R1. Measure the collector current. Divide.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new to electronics and self-taught and your explanation was at just the right level. I set up the above circuit and obtained Ic = 25.0mA and Ib = 78.8 microAmps giving beta = 254. Are you applying KVL to the circuit to find Ib?

Comment: @JR KVL is a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut here. You know the voltage across R1, from knowledge of the approximate VBE (or you could even measure VBE or the R1 voltage) and the battery voltage. But beta is such an ill-defined and variable 'constant' there's no need to measure it accurately. Hint, having set up this circuit, warm the transistor, see beta change. Change the base current by a factor of 2 or 10, see beta change. Put in another transistor of same batch and number, see beta change. When we design circuits professionally, we allow for at least a 3:1 beta variation.

Answer (score 0):

The beta is a theoretical quantity. It's not constant in practical transistors. It depends on the collector current and other operating conditions. And you can easily get individual transistors of the same type which do have -50% to +100% difference between their betas even in the same operation conditions. For that reason the manufacturers do not give the exact beta, they only promise some limits or in some cases only the minimum beta is specified.

The job to design the circuits so that beta variations do not spoil the manufacturing process is one of the basic skills in the art of electronic engineering. For some applications one must manually select transistors which have less beta variations than which is normal.

One way to reduce the effect of the beta variations is to use feedback. It can even be used when one measures the beta. The next circuit works without saturation in a wide range of different beta values:

[image]

The beta can as well be as low as 10 and as high as 600 with the same resistor values. The beta is calculated from voltmeter readings V1 and V2 with the next formula:

Beta = ((V2/R2)/(V1/R1))-1

The -1 comes from the fact that Ib and Ic both go through R2.

The leak of the transistor is assumed so low that V2=0 if the switch is not pressed. This circuit cannot cause a thermal runaway which is possible when the transistor is connected directly between a DC voltage supply having only a current meter and wires between the supply and the transistor.

Voltmeters must have much high resistances than the resistors in parallel. But that's no problem with the common 10 megaohm meters.

In theory it's possible that this circuits starts to oscillate at several megahertzes or catches radio noises due the long metering wires. Such effect can be suppressed by inserting a big enough capacitor, say 10 or 100 nF between the base and emitter of the transistor.

Comment: Beta specifications always are at a specified collector bias voltage and current.   For BC547B, it's 5V= Ice, 2 mA = Ic.  For 2N3904, a switch, that's 1V for Vce and 10 mA= Ic.

Comment: Yes, that can be printed on the datasheet (except Ice=volts.). But the questioner may still want to measure the beta to see for ex. how closely equal his 2 transistor individuals are. My circuit is a hobby project, not a spec verifying tool. But hopefully the questioner learns something.

Comment: @user208772 dude, please redraw that schematic so resistors are vertical, voltmeters vertical, that is generally following the positive voltage is upwards convention. It looks really untidy to a professional's eye right now, not setting a good example to noobs who are new to schematic drawing. I will grant that a schematic of this size is decipherable. A good schematic is about good communication, not just connection accuracy, telling a story through the position on the diagram. This is much more important when the schematic is more complicated.

Comment: @user208772 Yow!   That spellcheck is fierce, it knows the word 'ice' and I didn't notice the bogosity in time.   I'm pretty sure I typed Vce, and typing it right isn't good enough nowadays,